# Replace apostrophe SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 300K records.  In order to import them exactly as they existed in the original file.  The original file had pipe and tilde delimiters.  I replaced the pipe tilde with a pipe apostrophe so that the fields come in as text.  Now I need to get rid of the apostrophe.  The database is actually storing the fields as ntext not text.  The real crunch here is that many of the fields are zero padded fields and I need them to remain zero padded within the database.

Here is a sample of the text.  The first row is headers.

> Rec   'Article Number         'Substit.   'Group SKU              'Univ.
>   Prod. Code        'Article Description                        'Cat 
>     'Department Description                     'P.Cla      'Product CLass
>   Description                   'SC     'Sub CLass Description
>     'FLY    'Family Description                         'Vendor article
>   Number    'Pur    'Shi    'Gross weight           'UniWT      'Net weight
>     'Length                 'Width                  'Height
>     'UniDim     'Volume                 'UniVol     'Vendor Num     'Mfr Price
>     'Vendor Name                            'Mgr    'Category Mgr Name
>   00    '000000000022404373 '           '                   '43000670002
>     '67000 SBC House Blend T-Discs              '063    'Office Consumables
>     '12560  'Office Consumables                         '01 'Hot Beverage
>     '01     'COFFEE                                     '67000
>     'EA     'EA     '          14.700   'OZ     '          11.040   '
>   8.600     '           7.000   '           3.100   'IN     '           0.108   'FT3    '0000008228 '           'M BLOCK AND SONS INC
>     '017    'Patty Dunham       00  '000000000022404658 '           '
>     '400224046585       'NFR 2010 Merry Christmas 20Pk
>     '071    'Non-Merchandise Articles                   '30001  'OfficeMax
>     '11 'Merchandise                                '01     'Gift Card Program
>     'SV1003846              'EA     'EA     '          16.000   'OZ     '
>   16.000    '           4.250   '           1.950   '           4.500   'IN     '           0.022   'FT3    '0000934003 '           'CERIDIAN STORED
>   VALUE SOLUTIONS INC   'ZN1    'Non-Merchandise    00  '000000000022404676 '
>     '                   '75353105641        "'Bubble Envelope 10.5""x15
>   5Pk            "  '046    'Mailroom/Moving
>     '07303  'KRAFT WRAP/MAILERS                         '01 'MAILERS
>     '02     'BUBBLE                                     '756618
>     'EA     'EA     '          14.200   'OZ     '          14.200   '
>   16.500    '          11.250   '           1.250   'IN     '           0.134   'FT3    '0000008162 '           'SHURTECH BRANDS
>     '021    'Mailroom           00  '000000000022404756 '           '
>     '72512244814        'Champ .5mm 12pk Asstd Colors
>     '053    'Writing Instruments                        '10453  'Mechanical
>   Pencils                       '02 'Refillable
>     '01     'Added Value (Refilla                       'AL15BP12M
>     'EA     'EA     '           5.000   'OZ     '           4.100   '
>   7.600     '           4.200   '           1.000   'IN     '           0.018   'FT3    '0000000146 '           'PENTEL OF AMERICA LTD.
>     '004    'Bryant Spencer

I need to end up with text fields for all of the columns in the database, and the values as they appear in the sample above including leading zeros.

Comment: What are you using to import the data?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the table? Is it in SQL Server? If so do an update state like `update table set column = replace(column, '''', '')`. Then you can do an `alter table table_name alter column column_name varchar(some length)`. Though it sounds like you are talking about a Access database based off the types and leading 0s problem. Please clarify your question if the above did not answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/196e3/2) (with that query you can replace ' and '' with nothing):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  FIELD VARCHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO TEST(FIELD) VALUES(
  'Rec ''Article Number ''Substit. ''Group SKU ''Univ. Prod. Code ''Article Description ''Cat ''Department Description ''P.Cla ''Product CLass Description ''SC ''Sub CLass Description
''FLY ''Family Description ''Vendor article Number ''Pur ''Shi ''Gross weight ''UniWT ''Net weight
''Length ''Width ''Height
''UniDim ''Volume ''UniVol ''Vendor Num ''Mfr Price
''Vendor Name ''Mgr ''Category Mgr Name
00 ''000000000022404373 '' '' ''43000670002
''67000 SBC House Blend T-Discs ''063 ''Office Consumables
''12560 ''Office Consumables ''01 ''Hot Beverage
''01 ''COFFEE ''67000
''EA ''EA '' 14.700 ''OZ '' 11.040 ''
8.600 '' 7.000 '' 3.100 ''IN '' 0.108 ''FT3 ''0000008228 '' ''M BLOCK AND SONS INC
''017 ''Patty Dunham 00 ''000000000022404658 '' ''
''400224046585 ''NFR 2010 Merry Christmas 20Pk
''071 ''Non-Merchandise Articles ''30001 ''OfficeMax
''11 ''Merchandise ''01 ''Gift Card Program ''SV1003846 ''EA ''EA '' 16.000 ''OZ ''
16.000 '' 4.250 '' 1.950 '' 4.500 ''IN '' 0.022 ''FT3 ''0000934003 '' ''CERIDIAN STORED VALUE SOLUTIONS INC ''ZN1 ''Non-Merchandise 00 ''000000000022404676 '' '' ''75353105641 "''Bubble Envelope 10.5""x15 5Pk " ''046 ''Mailroom/Moving
''07303 ''KRAFT WRAP/MAILERS ''01 ''MAILERS
''02 ''BUBBLE ''756618
''EA ''EA '' 14.200 ''OZ '' 14.200 ''
16.500 '' 11.250 '' 1.250 ''IN '' 0.134 ''FT3 ''0000008162 '' ''SHURTECH BRANDS
''021 ''Mailroom 00 ''000000000022404756 '' ''
''72512244814 ''Champ .5mm 12pk Asstd Colors
''053 ''Writing Instruments ''10453 ''Mechanical Pencils ''02 ''Refillable
''01 ''Added Value (Refilla ''AL15BP12M
''EA ''EA '' 5.000 ''OZ '' 4.100 ''
7.600 '' 4.200 '' 1.000 ''IN '' 0.018 ''FT3 ''0000000146 '' ''PENTEL OF AMERICA LTD.
''004 ''Bryant Spencer'
  )

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(FIELD,'''',''),'''''','') FROM TEST
```